# How to push a commit to Github from a CircleCI build using a personal access token

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, circleci, cd

When executing a build for git repository `giantswarm/docs-content` in CircleCI, I'd like to push a commit to another repository `giantswarm/docs`.

I have this in the `deployment` section of `circle.yml`:

```
git config credential.helper cache
git config user.email "<some verified email>"
git config user.name "Github Bot"
git clone --depth 1 https://${GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/giantswarm/docs.git
cd docs/
git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger build and publishing via docs-content"
git push -u origin master
```

This [fails](https://circleci.com/gh/giantswarm/docs-content/67) in the very last command with this error message:

```
ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

The `GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN` environment variable is set to a user's personal access token, which has been created with `repo` scope to access the private repo `giantswarm/docs`. In addition, I added the user to a team that has admin permissions for that repo.

That series of commands works just fine when I execute it in a fresh Ubuntu VM. Any idea why it doesn't on CircleCI?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this method of auth with GitHub. Have you tried simply using SSH keys? Most GitHub operations on CircleCI use SSH keys (including what I do myself) and it works very well. Also, less config lines to setup in the deployment section.

Comment: @FelicianoTech I tried that too, yes. With error in git clone: `ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: And you used the SSH address for the repo that GitHub gives you in their UI?

Comment: @FelicianoTech Yes, I used the address `git@github.com:giantswarm/docs.git` with SSH

Comment: I'm getting this error too, but on Travis CI. Up to October 29 it was working fine (doing a `git push` using a personal access token). I didn't change anything, but all builds after that have been failing with the error you mentioned.

Comment: Update: other Travis CI users reported the same issue as me ([#8680](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8680), [#8686](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8686)), but I'm still not sure what the fix is.

Comment: Update: I realise now that the `git push` is actually using SSH (because that's how Travis originally cloned the repo), not HTTPS as I thought. So the personal access token is not even being used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the hint by [Ali Amin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753997/1228491) I now have this working solution:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Clone docs
          working_directory: ~/workdir
          command: |
            git clone --depth 1 https://${DOCS_GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/giantswarm/docs.git
      - deploy:
          name: Trigger docs deployment
          working_directory: ~/workdir/docs
          command: |
            git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=120'
            git config user.email "<email>"
            git config user.name "Deployment Bot"
            git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger deployment"
            # Push quietly to prevent showing the token in log
            git push -q https://${DOCS_GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/giantswarm/docs.git master
```

Some notes:

- The `git clone` is first.
- All subsequent `git` commands have to be executed in the clone directory. `working_directory` simplifies this a great deal.
- The token `DOCS_GITHUB_TOKEN` is a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) with `repo` scope for the target repository.

Comment: How do you actually make personal access token for a specific repo? I am failing to find that option anywhere.

Comment: @FredyC Have you figured it out yet? If not, you can follow the [steps here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line).

Answer (score 22):

I've used

```
git push -q https://${GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN}@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git master
```

and it worked.
Update it to be:

```
# Push changes
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=120'
git config user.email "<email>"
git config user.name "<user-name>"
git add .
git commit -m "Update via CircleCI"
# Push quietly to prevent showing the token in log
git push -q https://${GITHUB_PERSONAL_TOKEN}@github.com/giantswarm/docs.git master
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve my problem, however I had to change things a bit. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48763205/1228491

Comment: Thanks, you can use `${CIRCLE_BRANCH}` when running `git push`

Comment: Note that if you get an error it will still log your token

Comment: what would this look like for SSH instead of https?

Comment: @Corbfon get rid of error logs by adding `> /dev/null 2>&1` at the end of your `git push` command. Learn more about that [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/).

Answer (score 2):

Although embedding the token into the command works for this case it might not work for all cases and doesn't answer the question.

1. Other cases would include scripts that dont expose direct access to the `git` command. They rely on the `GH_TOKEN` variable being set and you wouldn't be able to inject it as in the example.
2. It doesn't answer the question:

> Any idea why it doesn't on CircleCI?

On CircleCI support forum there is an answer about this:

https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018860473-How-to-push-a-commit-back-to-the-same-repository-as-part-of-the-CircleCI-job

> Running git push results in "ERROR: The key you are authenticating with has been marked as read only."
>
> The deploy key that the project is configured with, by default when you add a project on CircleCI, only has read access, so a key with write permissions needs to be configured to be used, to avoid the above error message. Please ensure that a user key or a read-write deployment key has been configured for the project

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/gh-bb-integration/#creating-a-github-deploy-key

After going through this process you should have a deploy key with write permissions that allows the push.